# Perl: write speed mystery?

Tags: performance, perl, hard-drive

How can the output rate be higher than hard disk write rate?

**Update 1**: I have changed the following:

1. Turned off antivirus. No change.
2. Inserted new physical disk and used the first partition
   for the test. (The disk for the initial test was on the
   last partition, separate from the system partition, but
   on the same physical disk.). Result: there is the same
   cyclic pattern, but the system is **no longer
   unresponsive** during the test. The write speed is
   somewhat higher (could be due to using the first
   partition and/or no longer interference with the system
   partition). Preliminary conclusion: there was some kind
   of interference from the system partition.
3. Installed 64 bit Perl. The cycles are gone and
   everything is stable on a 2 second timescale: 55% CPU on
   the single core, write speed about 65 MB/s.
4. Tried on the original drive with 64 bit Perl. Result:
   somewhere in-between. Cycles of 8 seconds, CPU 20-50%,
   35 - 65 MB/sec (instead of deep cycles of 0-100%, 0 -
   120 MB/sec). The system is only mildly unresponsive.
   Write speed is 50 MB/sec. This supports the interference theory.
5. Flushing in the Perl script. Not tried yet.

---

OK, I got past the [first hurdle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373372). I have written a Perl
script that can generate a very large text file (e.g. 20 GB) and
is essentially just a number of:

```
print NUMBERS_OUTFILE $line;
```

where $line is a long string  with a "\n" at the end.

When the Perl script starts the write rate is about 120 MB/s
(consistent between what is computed by the script,
[Process Explorer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_Explorer) and "IO Write Bytes/sec" for process Perl
in Performance Monitor.) and 100% CPU on the single core it
is running on. This rate is, I believe, higher than write
speed of the hard disk.

Then after some time (e.g. 20 seconds and 2.7 GB written)
the whole system becomes very unresponsive and CPU drops to
0%. This last for e.g. 30 seconds. The average write speed
over these two phases is consistent with the write speed of
the hard disk. The times and sizes mentioned in this
paragraph varies a lot from run to run. The range 1 GB
to 4.3 GB for the first phase has been observed so far.
Here is a [transcript for the run with 4.3 GB](http://www.pil.sdu.dk/1/until2039-12-31/PerlPerfTranscript_2009-09-07b.txt).

There are several of these cycles for a 9.2 GB text file
generated in the test:

[image]

What is going on?

---

Full [Perl script](http://pmortensen.eu/1/until2039-12-31/generate_2009-09-07.pl.html) and [BAT driver script](http://pmortensen.eu/1/until2039-12-31/generate_2009-09-07.bat.html) (HTML formatted with
the pre tag). If the two environment variables MBSIZE and
OUTFILE are setup then the Perl script should be able to run
unchanged on other platforms than Windows.

Platform: Perl 5.10.0 from ActiveState;
          (initially 32 bit, later 64 bit); build 1004.
          Windows XP x64 SP2, no page file, 8 GB RAM, AMD quad core CPU,
          500 GB Green Caviar hard disks (write speed 85
          MB/s?).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am with everyone else who is saying that the problem is buffers filling and then emptying. Try turning on [autoflush](http://perldoc.perl.org/IO/Handle.html) to avoid having a buffer (in Perl):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use IO::Handle;

my $filename = "output.txt";

open my $numbers_outfile, ">", $filename
    or die "could not open $filename: $!";

$numbers_outfile->autoflush(1);

#each time through the loop should be 1 gig
for (1 .. 20) {
    #each time though the loop should be 1 meg
    for (1 .. 1024) {
        #print 1 meg of Zs
        print {$numbers_outfile} "Z" x (1024*1024)
    }
}
```

Buffers can be good if you are going to print a little, do so work, print a litte, do some work, etc.  But if you are just going to be blasting data onto disk, they can cause odd behavior.  You may also need to disable any write caching your filesystem is doing.

Comment: Thanks. I have now tried 64 bit Perl (see updated question), but the next step will be to try turning on autoflush.

Comment: Remember, you may also need to modify your filesystem if it is keeping buffers around.

Comment: autoflush will make a system call after every print element. In your example performance will be good because it is 1 MB at a time. But if you print 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' it will be very bad because that is four system calls of one char each...watch out for that.

Answer (score 5):

All data is cached in buffers before being effectively layed in the physical disk. A buffer from the system, another inside the disk itself (a 32MB buffer probably). While you fill those buffers, your program run at full speed and 100% CPU. Once the buffers are full, your program get to wait for the disk, which is much, much slower than memory and buffers, and this wait makes you stop consuming all this CPU.

Maybe you can make your code "wait for the disk" from the start, by using some Perl equivalent to `fflush()`.

Comment: I expect there to be file buffers. But not several GB in size (?)

Comment: On linux systems buffers are usually configured to spread to nearly all free RAM.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe the OS is writing to disk as fast as it can (85 MB/s), and is putting the excess 35 MB/s in a buffer, and when it fills, is pausing the app to flush the buffer. Since the buffer is drained at 85 MB/s, you'd expect it to take 35/85 = ~0.4 times as long to drain as to fill. That's broadly compatible with your graph, if i squint enough.

You can estimate the size of the buffer as the product of the pause time and the disk speed.

Answer (score 3):

Look at the graph!
The green line indicates the average disk queue length. At one moment, it gets a peak and the CPU goes to 0 afterwards. IO Writes also goes to 0. It goes back to normal until a second peak is shown. Then CPU and IO writes return to normal. Then both IO and CPU drop again, to go up again at the next Queue peak. And again down, then up again...

It could be that the disk is doing the physical writes at that moment. However, it could also be that the system is doing a disk validation at that moment, reading the dat it just wrote to validate the writes, making sure the data is written correctly.

Another thing I notice is the 2.7 GB size. Since you're running this on a Windows system, I become a bit suspicious since that's about the amount of memory that Windows can handle, as a 32-bits process. The 64-bits Windows will provide the application up to 3 GB of RAM (a bit less) but then it needs to release it again. You might want to use Process Explorer to check the amount of RAM in use and the amount of IO reads.

And perhaps use a 64-bits Perl version...

Comment: Regarding 2.7 GB: I don't know if more than 3 GB is possible, but it can happen already at 1 GB. For instance just before I wrote this I ran it again and the first phase ended at 1.2 GB (somewhere in between 1139 MB and 1273 MB).

Comment: What do you mean by amount of RAM? Amount for the Perl process? "Private bytes" for the Perl process stays constant at 4 MB during the run. About 6.3 GB RAM is free when the script is started.

Comment: I just tried another run. This time the first phase ended at approximately 4.3 GB (somewhere in between 4.19 GB and 4.41 GB [4288.3 MB; 4513.7 MB]). Here is a transcript of the run: http://www.pil.sdu.dk/1/until2039-12-31/PerlPerfTranscript_2009-09-07b.txt

Comment: I will try to install the 64 bit version of Perl from ActiveState and test it.

Comment: The problem with Process Explorer is that the system becomes so unresponsive that there are no screen updates in Process Explorer. Performance Monitor also stops updating and I don't know if it actually samples correctly during the unresponsive period.

Comment: A 32-bits process won't be able to use more than 3 GB of Windows. One GB is always reserved for Windows and part of the memory will be used by Perl itself, plus some data. It could be that some add-in/plugin is allocating this RAM without reporting this to your graph. It does seem like it's just filling it's own in-memory buffer first before writing it to disk, although the disk seems to report write IO.

Comment: The 64-bits version, if available, might be more optimal for a 64-bits system. There's no guarantee that it will behave better but if it's something that uses the RAM for some buffering or whatever, you would at least have a much bigger buffer since the 64-bits version will be able to use all, while the 32-bits version is limited...

Comment: I have tried the 64 bit version now (see updated question). It is definitely better. But it would be good to known exactly why.

Comment: Well, the 64-bits version is able to use much more memory than the 32-bits version. It could be that there's some kind of buffering going on somewhere in RAM. As a test, disable the swap file. Or all swap files if you have multiple! It's not practical but the effect might indicate a memory-related issue. (Turn them back on after the test!)